# Getting related rows based on columns outside the initial select query

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having trouble figuring out an efficient or elegant way to do this type of query in SQL.

Say I have a table called "People" and I know one person's ID and want to find all other people who are the same age and sex as that person. The desired result is shown here:

People

```
PersonID    Age    Sex
       1     22      M
       2     24      F
       3     36      M
       4     22      M
       5     77      F
       6     22      F
```

Desired Result

```
PersonID    Age    Sex
       1     22      M
       4     22      M
```

Theoretically, this can be done in two steps: first, query the sex and age of the person based on the ID, and then second query the entire table based on that age-sex combination:

```
SELECT Age, Sex FROM People WHERE PersonID = 4
```

```
SELECT * FROM People WHERE Age = <age of Person 4> AND Sex = <sex of person 4>
```

I am currently working with python pandas `read_sql` function using SQL syntax so I have been able to work around this by "post-processing" things in Python and end up having to do these two queries. The problem is I know that this isn't efficient and should be doable with just a single query. I was trying to also use `RIGHT JOIN` to do this, but don't see the right approach. Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is with a self join:

```
SELECT p1.* 
FROM People p1 INNER JOIN people p2
ON p2.Age = p1.Age AND p2.Sex = p1.Sex
WHERE p2.PersonID = 4
```

Comment: @teepee see this demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pAN2FZcFx4h9bbK5d3chUN/0 (it is for SQLite but the code is standard SQL) There are no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE to retrieve the values you want to filter on and then simply join on those values. You had the "guts" of this query, you just did not put them together.

```
with cte as (select Age, Sex from dbo.People where PersonID = 4)
select pep.PersonID, pep.Age, pep.Sex  
from dbo.People as pep 
inner join cte on pep.Age = cte.Age and pep.Sex = cte.Sex
order by ...;
```

Notice the inclusion of the schema name (presumably dbo), formal column list, an order by clause, and a statement terminator. Practice good habits.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*
from people p
where exists (select 1
              from people p2
              where p2.age = p.age and p2.sex = p.sex and p2.personId = 4
             );
```